# Writing "" value in column for missing geopy Nominatim dictionary key (raise KeyError) using Lambda with Pandas

Tags: dataframe, dictionary, lambda, geopy

I am looking for a way to allow for the exemption of a missing dictionary key while parsing through geopy gecode.reverse.  I'm writing the dictionary to a column df['Street'] using Lambda to parse through the lat/longs from another column.

```
geo = Nominatim(user_agent = "Standard_Road", timeout = 10)
geocode = RateLimiter(geo.geocode, min_delay_seconds = .75)
tqdm.pandas()
df['geom'] = df['Latitude'].map(str) + ',' + df['Longitude'].map(str)
df['geom'][0]
df['Street'] = df['geom'].progress_apply(lambda x: geo.reverse(x, language = 'en').raw['address']['road'])
```

This returns the road value in the dictionary until the key 'road' does not exist.  So I'm trying to handle the exemption with a simple if else statement to return a None or "" value in the column, however, what I have tried below is raising the same KeyError.

```
df['Street'] = df['geom'].progress_apply(lambda x: geo.reverse(x, language = 'en').raw['address']['road'] 
    if df['geom'].get(geo.reverse(x, language = 'en').raw['address']['road']) 
    else geo.reverse(x, language = 'en').raw['address']['road'] == None)
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, but maybe someone has a better solution.

I created a variable which only consisted of the dictionary as a whole.  At that point I was able to call .get to create the new column in the dataframe.  This allowed for the None exemption which populated the street data I needed and leaving blank values where no key existed in the dictionary.

```
### Geo search for consistent street & zip.  Creating new columns 'Street' & 'Zip Code' 
geo = Nominatim(user_agent = "Standard_Road", timeout = 10)
geocode = RateLimiter(geo.reverse, min_delay_seconds = 2)
tqdm.pandas()
g = df['Latitude'].map(str) + ',' + df['Longitude'].map(str)
g[0]
d = g.progress_apply(lambda x: geo.reverse(x).raw['address'])
df['Street'] = [d.get('road') for d in d]
df['Zip Code'] = [d.get('postcode') for d in d]
```